# Ivy compilation error - component not exported from top level entry file

Tags: angular, stenciljs, ng-packagr, angular-ivy

I am following the Stencil guide for configuring an angular output target [here](https://stenciljs.com/docs/angular#adding-angular-output-target) and am facing a problem when it comes to exporting the generated angular components to make them accessible in a production build.

The generated angular directory (from stencil output targets) appears like so

[image]

when running a production build I get the error

[image]

I have seen this error before in other projects I have built, and I know I need to add an export of the components in the entry file for the lib.

In my top-level `index.ts` I have

```
export {DIRECTIVES} from './generated/directives';
export * from './lib/core-components-angular.module';
```

And in the `generated/directives/index.ts` from a stencil I have

```
import * as d from './proxies';

export const DIRECTIVES = [
  d.MyComponent
];
```

As per the stencil docs, I am pretty sure I have followed the steps they suggest

[image]

I am able to get the build to succeed if I use explicit component exports so

```
export {
    MyComponent,
    OtherComponent
} from './generated/directives/proxies';
```

But of course, the documented approach would be far better as a stencil will keep the exported `DIRECTIVES` constant updated for me as more components get added

So I am not sure where I am going wrong here, something trivial I am sure, can someone point out the problem, please?

Comment: Isn't it documented here https://stenciljs.com/docs/angular#why-aren-t-my-custom-interfaces-exported-from-within-the-index-d-ts-file ?